# Can I recover a deleted VLC history file?

Tags: vlc

Is there any way to recovering recently used files of vlc in ubuntu? or How can I reach this text file which saved on my hdd?

Comment: but Where should I scan in my file directories? Where vlc saved this text file?

Comment: Maybe in `~/.vlc`? I don't know, just guessing.

Comment: there isn't file like .vlc please help I have to reach this deleted list.

Comment: Ummmm... `~/.vlc` would be a hidden *folder* in your home directory.

Comment: ok. I found but when I deleted recently files this file didn't delete, this file changed. In this point can I recover old lines?